# php 5.6 is showing an error on variable scope

Tags: php, laravel

I am running both mamp with php 5.5 and laravel forge with php 5.6- this works fine on mamp/5.5 but in laravel forge i get an undefined error for the variable $date

```
<?

$date = date('l, dS F');
$already = false;

foreach($events as $event){?>
    <?

    if(date('l, dS F',strtotime($event->start_time)) != $date){
        $date = date('l, dS F',strtotime($event->start_time));

    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h4 style="color:#003399">{{$date}}</h4> **<------ this throws Undefined variable: date**
        </div>
    </div>
```

This seems really strange to me

laravel error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fblyx.jpg

Comment: {{$date}} is not inside a `<?php .... ?>` tag set.

Comment: its blade templates so it renders as such http://imgur.com/mI97XOR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [short-tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) are not enabled.

You will probably see your php source code when you view the source in your browser.

You can either enable short tags or use `<?php` instead of `<?`.

Comment: Yea sorry my mistake, I changed it back when I realised I was being a dip stick